# Voting glitch in Blackberry browser

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting, blackberry

On my BlackBerry 9700 (OS 5.0.0.351) the site (StackOverflow svn revision: 6532) works reasonably well. Even dynamic features like adding/editing comments are no problem. Call me masochistic if you like. ;-)

In any case, when voting on a post, I get the orange `"An error has occurred - please retry your request."` message after a few seconds. The vote however is counted just fine. Given the limited JS debugging capabilities of the device I can't really investigate more closely.

Looking at `question.js` this error message appears only once in the source, in a jQuery `ajax()` error callback. This would indicate that the server did not reply 200 OK to the POST. Maybe someone with access to the server logs can spend a few minutes on this? I voted on SO question 2470907 a few minutes ago, if that helps filtering.

Comment: I sometimes get that error even on Chrome, so I'm not entirely surprised if you see it on a Blackberry.

Comment: It's just reproducible on the BB. :) It may also be that the request goes through, the answer is 200 OK but is lost in the BES infrastructure for some reason. The only way to know is to look at the server logs, I guess.

Comment: Voting to close this. Seems to be too localized or to hard to reproduce, might also be solved as a side-effect of newer revisions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [An error has occurred - please retry your request while voting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46989/an-error-has-occurred-please-retry-your-request-while-voting)

Comment: This is a problem that occurs with most browsers and platforms intermittently.  How in the world do you sign into OpenId on the Blackberry when the buttons don't show up?

Answer (score 2):

We were just waiting patiently for BlackBerry to die out, here's how that played out:

- Con: Unfortunately, they didn't die off according to our master plan (section 13, part C).
- Pro: They switched to webkit!
- Con: Google stopped contributing to webkit, doh.
- Pro: They renamed to BlackBerry, what everyone thought they were called anyway.
- Con/Pro: Still not dead yet - this may be good or bad, depends on what Apple does to webkit.

I lost track.

**But!**, their browsers did get better!  Voting works now! As do images, styles, and even sometimes tables!  Ok maybe not tables, depends on how old your BlackBerry is `</cheapshot>`