# An error has occurred - please retry your request while voting

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting

For some reason I am recently getting a lot of "An error has occurred - please retry your request" error while voting and other ajax things. This started about week or two ago.

I am using Windows Vista and Chrome.

I am also [experiencing errors while editing posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47082/i-am-getting-oops-something-bad-happened-quite-often-while-editing-posts) and problems when [posting comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48711/blank-page-when-adding-a-comment).

It seems that this error occurs only with Google Chrome and not with Firefox. My chrome is version 4.1.249.1064 (45376) and Firefox is version 3.6.3.

Comment: Have you cleared your cached?

Comment: Well, I cleared cache. The error has not occurred at least yet.

Comment: This happens to me sometimes (quite rarely) when I try to post an answer using Google Chrome on Windows 7 x64. I type the answer and when I click post I get a 500 error page. I close the browser, reopen it, retype the answer and same thing happens. Impossible to post the answer to this particular question. If then I copy paste the url of the question into IE or FireFox, retype the answer, it works just fine. Then I go back to Chrome, navigate to the same question, try to edit the text, same I get 500 error again. It already happened to me a few times and it's quite annoying.

Comment: The error has occurred at least once after clearing the cache.

Comment: Clearing the cache didn't help. This error still occurs.

Comment: Juha - also try restarting your browser. I experienced this as also , and after restarting Chrome, all was well.

Comment: @rlb.usa: restarting does not help.

Comment: thanks for the update. We're looking at ways to make the feedback better (see my answer for an example of that), but it's a bit low pri at the moment.

Comment: @Jeff, I just tried and the fix didn't work for me. I got this error again: http://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/posts/2252674/edit-submit/f9a6ed24-e112-4b8f-a756-dddf2a62ed9d  (XSRF validation: Request form value 'fkey' did not match CurrentUser.XSRFFormValue)

Answer (score 7):

Can you provide steps to reproduce the problem?

edit: I added the actual error message to the HTML of the error page in an HTML comment. View source on the error page and look for:

```
<!--
Actual error:
This is a test exception generated by SimpleErrorHandler 
1.0.3764.33883. Please disregard.
-->
```

So, **provide me that**. I suspect this is XSRF stuff you guys are running afoul of, as we suppress all those "errors".. they're caused by networking problems 99% of the time.

edit: We did find a small bug that might have caused this in rare circumstances, for users who tend to switch IP addresses rapidly. Let us know if it's any better after today (May 14 '10).

Comment: It's about time you added an error code!

Comment: do not have prepro steps yet, but this occurs only with chrome, not with firefox.

Comment: The May 14 fix did not work for me. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @juha then AFAIK your internet connection to us is a bit busted :(

Comment: BTW I can't get this to work with IE 11, so I just use Chrome. I could send you a fiddler trace if you like. I suspect it's an issue inside our domain.

Answer (score 0):

I visit SO almost exclusively on Windows/Chrome, and I cannot reproduce nor do I recall seeing anything like this very frequently. If you see it beginning to happen more, open up a network monitor and see what scripts/requests are failing, and where - that will help diagnose the issue real quick.