# Linked and Related sections contain duplicate links to questions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, related-questions, linked-questions

The *Linked* and *Related* sections sometimes contain a link to same same question.

See for example [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46989/an-error-has-occurred-please-retry-your-request), where one of the *Linked* questions is same as the first of the *Related* questions.

I think that this is redundant and duplicate links should be removed from *Related* section.

Comment: A related feature request to change this functionality: [Remove post from the related list if it's in the linked list already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357145/335251). There's also a related discussion here: [Do related linked questions really need to be linked twice?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225566/335251).

Answer (score 13):

I agree, this can get pretty bad, especially on meta sites. Here's an example:

[image: Programmers example]

I think the sidebar is pretty valuable real estate, and wasting space with posts that are already mentioned seems like a waste of same.

Answer (score 4):

If Pops is right that the duplication adds info, then that extra info would be even more visible (and eat less screen space) were the duplicates moved to a third list *Linked and Related*.

Or, create a third list *Linked and Unrelated!*

If measurements by staff confirm that durron597 is right that entries in *Linked* are often duplicated, then little info is added by the duplication, and the duplication is unjustified.

Comment: This is more of a question post using this as a "link".

Answer (score 2):

I disagree.  It's not truly redundant because, though the links point to the same place, the fact that they're in both lists provides additional information.  Specifically, it tells you that the system agrees that the link someone inserted is, in fact, related.  The links are already pretty unobtrusive, so the small benefit outweighs the even smaller cost.