# If a question is linked, how can it be at the top of the "related" list?

Tags: bug, questions, related-questions, linked-questions

Consider [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27686382/how-can-i-dump-all-nvcc-preprocessor-defines), and look at the side-column:
[image]

The same question is both linked-to, and the top related. That doesn't make sense. If it were lower on the related list - then, maybe, well, I don't know, it doesn't make much sense to me either (see [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48624/linked-and-related-sections-contain-duplicate-links-to-questions)). But surely not the top spot?

Comment: Why not the top spot? If it's related, it could also be more related than all others and therefore have earned the top spot.

Comment: @Trilarion:The picture is worth a 1000 words.

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate of this bug report, marked as [status-bydesign]: [Linked and Related sections contain duplicate links to questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48624/335251). (There's also a related feature request: [Remove post from the related list if it's in the linked list already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357145/335251) - and a related discussion: [Do related linked questions really need to be linked twice?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225566/335251).)