# Should items in the Linked question appear again in the Related question list directly below? Could they be removed somehow?

Tags: discussion, design, linked-questions, related-questions

[image]

The Politics SE question [How much of Hu Jintao's being escorted out was seen by Chinese at home? Was it live? Did they see it close up as seen internationally?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/76307/16047) includes a linked question which now appears in both the Linked question list and the Related question list. The timing I recollect is that it appeared first in Related and afterward I linked to it in a comment.

I've often wondered if the sometimes substantial overlap in the two displayed lists was the *best use of precious space on the page*, and if the Linked items should be pruned from the Related items. To that end I'd like to ask:

**Question:** Should items in the Linked question appear again in the Related question list directly below? Could they be removed somehow?

Comment: A related bug report, marked as [status-bydesign]: [Linked and Related sections contain duplicate links to questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48624/335251). There's also a related feature request: [Remove post from the related list if it's in the linked list already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357145/335251) - and a related discussion: [Do related linked questions really need to be linked twice?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225566/335251). (Your post seems like a duplicate of one of the latter two, since it's tagged [discussion] but asks for a change in functionality.)

Comment: @V2Blast things have changed a lot in the last decade, I'm not sure "by design" reflects current thinking. To move forward why not close the old question as a duplicate of the present instead? I don't think anyone ever intentionally designed this repeating.

Comment: I mean, it's definitely not a bug - it's working as it was intended to, so [status-bydesign] is the right tag for the bug report. The community can still request that it be changed - as it has, via that [feature-request] post I linked. The [feature-request] and [discussion] posts do not have any official response, so it's better to support the existing feature-request for a change in this functionality rather than just making a duplicate of those posts, unless your suggestion is materially different from those posts.

Comment: @V2Blast okay got it. I've added a bounty to the feature request.