# Discrepancy between vote counts in Linked list and Related list

Tags: bug, related-questions, linked-questions

While viewing the question *[How does Santa protect himself from IP lawsuits?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/31987/how-does-santa-protect-himself-from-ip-lawsuits)*, I saw the "Linked" and "Related" questions lists. There is a duplicate question in both lists ([which is apparently by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48624/linked-and-related-sections-contain-duplicate-links-to-questions)) but with a discrepancy in the vote counts:

[image: Linked "How can Santa exist when adults buy the toys" - 47 votes; Related "How can Santa exist when adults buy the toys" - 48 votes]

Comment: As far as I can tell, the Linked questions list is heavily cached, and re-calculated only once a day or so. The Related questions list is also cached, but for much shorter time, think few minutes.

Comment: Haha! "Fixed" by forcing a re-calculation by posting a comment on the linked/related question back to that question you mentioned, then deleting the comment. Based on [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/187734/152859).