# Problems casting close/reopen votes

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, ajax

This is the same problem (or at least the same symptoms) as [46989](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46989/an-error-has-occurred-please-retry-your-request-while-voting), but that was marked complete. I've been getting this pretty regularly, maybe 6 times in the last week:

[image: An error has occurred - please retry your request]

It happens on both close and reopen votes. I looked the most recent time for the error information [Jeff mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46989/an-error-has-occurred-please-retry-your-request-while-voting/48622#48622), but couldn't find it. Is this a known/common problem, or is it just me?

I should probably mention since it was provided in the other post: I'm using Firefox 3.6.3 on Linux

Comment: Confirmed on Safari: I took the fourth close vote on a question (today): same error message / question got closed some time later (I was still in the list of those who closed (in the last spot). EDIT: this was the question I was talking about ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fixed - we had to make some changes in how we were locking questions during close voting.

Answer (score 1):

I get the same issue, however with just plain voting. When I do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> the page fully refreshes and I don't get the same problem, but it occurs quite often.

Comment: Refreshing doesn't fix it for me, I usually have to wait a few minutes and then everything seems to be fine

Answer (score 1):

I get a waiting icon -- which I've never been able to out wait.  The vote seems to have been cast, since if I refresh after a question that I've voted to close has been closed I see that mine is one of the close votes.  This happens for me on both Safari/Mac and IE8/Windows.

Comment: I've had the wait icon before; usually it turns into the error dialog, but it takes a minute. I almost never have the vote go through, although it did on the [one I screenshotted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945639/for-beginning-programming)