# Reopen votes disappeared - bug?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting, reopen-closed

[Edit: not a bug, it's a feature]

Yesterday [this ex-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006550/how-is-ios-pronounced) definitely had 2 reopen votes. Today the total was reset to zero. I tried re-casting the vote and it was accepted fine, and is still there now.

I thought maybe they're just reset after a certain length of time, but I can't see any mention of this and apparently reopen votes [have been buggy lately](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51865/problems-casting-close-reopen-votes) so I thought it was worth a mention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Close and reopen votes expire after 4 days if the question doesn't actually get closed/reopened (i.e. doesn't reach 5 total votes).

You can check the [FAQ for closed questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question-in-stackoverflow-how-do-they-work) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Close and reopen votes decay after 4 days. The question was closed on Jun 9th and it is now Jun 15th, so it may be that those 2 reopen votes were cast over 4 days ago, when the question was first closed.