# Close Votes expire too soon for low-traffic tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, vote-to-close

On low-traffic tags, a bad question may pick up one or two close votes, but simply hasn't been viewed by very many people with the close-vote privilege.

So, [after 4 days, the close votes expire](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question/10583#10583), and SO remains cluttered with poor questions.

Possible examples which all meet one or more close reasons:

[Q#5037300](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5037300/), 
  [Q#6015594](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6015594/), 
  [Q#3315186](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3315186/), 
  [Q#4546611](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4546611/), 
  [Q#6543834](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6543834/), 
  [Q#6444752](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6444752/)

Also a good chunk of [these Google results](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22Know%20someone%20who%20can%20answer%22%20site:stackoverflow.com&hl=en&tbm=#q=%22Know%20someone%20who%20can%20answer%22%20site:stackoverflow.com&hl=en&prmdo=1&tbas=0&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:4/1/2007,cd_max:1/13/2011,sbd:1&prmd=ivns&source=lnt&sa=X&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.) probably could be closed.

---

Note that this phenomenon can also cause undo "churn" and fallback to the flagging system.

For example,  see [What Happened Here? Voted to Close 4 Days Ago, but No Close Votes Today?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56614/148310) (and [similar questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53702/148310))...

1. A user notes a question that needs closing, votes to close it, and then later notices that the evil question has escaped justice.
2. The user then [opens a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/63131/148310) on Meta and/or fires off a few flags.
3. Only after lots of community involvement and moderator intervention is the [bad question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3187923/331508) closed.

---

### Proposed solution:

Close votes (and probably reopen votes) only expire after **all** of these conditions are met:

1. 4 days have passed since the *last* close vote.
2. The question has received 100 views.  (Note that the 6 example questions were viewed: 64, 54, 95, 121, 56, and 50 times, respectively, before this question was posted.)
3. The question was viewed by, say, 20 people who had the close-vote privilege.

Comment: kind of strange that we allow a 7 and 30 day time range here: http://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=close&daterange=last30days

Comment: @waffles:  I (¿and probably all non-mod users?) cannot see that link. Perhaps a description and/or screenshot for us plebes?

Comment: It's a page that shows all pending close votes, recently closed and recently re-opened.

Comment: @brock the link waffles posted is a 10k privilege http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools

Comment: see also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87979/make-close-votes-live-for-a-given-number-of-views-rather-than-given-time

Comment: @Ian Ringrose: Thanks, I swear I searched for similar questions before posting. I would have linked to yours if I'd found it.

Comment: This is only a partial solution for uncommon tags. First of all, uncommon tags have less persons that have access to moderator tools, so 5 votes are really required. Second, there are far fewer people that look at the questions, let alone cast close votes. This means that we now have a huge backlog of questions waiting to be closed, and questions that really need to be closed are not actually closed.   And they ***need*** to be closed, just saying that there are less people interested in the question so it does not need to be closed is a terrible, horrible argument. PS did vote UP.

Comment: Why number of views by people without close vote should matter at all ? Also reopening of closed questions (typically false duplicates) looks way harder than closing.  The why is because if a question was initially closed as a false duplicate, it means that it at least lloks superficailly similar to another one, henceforth reopening would mean more thorough - time consuming - reviews, not the typical one minute review and close. Henceforth reopening votes should last longer than close votes.

Comment: Another problem is that reopening always happen on a closed question and by the rule above it means it *has* more than 100 views. The limits should definitely be different for reopening.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Brock, this is GENIUS!

I am hereby using my super-upvote on this [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request):

> Close votes (and probably reopen votes) only expire after all of these conditions are met:
>
> 1. 4 days have passed since the *last* close vote.
> 2. The question has more than 100 views.

(#3 is kind of impossible to implement, and anyway, I think these two changes are huge.)

Comment: Am I right to assume that it is "more then 100 view since the last close vote"?

Comment: @ian no, it is 100 views period; we don't track views over time, views is literally an i++ counter.

Comment: @Jeff, you could put the "current view count" as well the the date on the "vote to close" record when a vote is cast.

Comment: It works fine for closing, but reopening is way harder. The why is because if a question was initially closed as a false duplicate, it means that it at least lloks superficailly similar to another one, henceforth reopening would mean more thorough - time consuming - reviews, not the typical one minute review and close. Henceforth reopening votes should last longer than close votes. Close and reopening are not really symmetrical: different limits for close and reopening should apply.

Answer (score 5):

I seriously support 2. and 3. They are genuinely good suggestions. If we need to flag, then what are close votes for? No offence to @Robert Harvey.

Comment: #3 is actually not that great of a suggestion (even it was easily implementable, which it isn't); just because 10 users with 3k rep viewed the question doesn't mean those 10 users know or care about how to cast close votes -- or are even paying attention.