# Has the expiry of votes to close changed?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

Unless I'm forgetting what I did five minutes ago, the expiry of votes to close seems to have changed.

In [Access a module's class variables inside a class in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833361/access-a-modules-class-variables-inside-a-class-in-ruby) , it's saying that there's one vote to close (mine), but it looks like I did it on July 26.

Sorry that the following circle isn't hand-drawn, but at least it's hand typed:

```
             /-------\
|link|edit|c|ose (1)|f|ag|
             \-------/
                  ^
                  |
                  |
```

Comment: +1 for the hand-typed "circle"!  Well, if yer talkin' sense, yer need a vote anyways!

Comment: How do you see when a close vote was casted?

Comment: @NullUserExceptionஇ_இ: I'm assuming it's July 26 based on the comment automatically created by the exact duplicate close vote. I can't be 100% sure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The change took place [a little over 8 weeks ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97556/close-votes-expire-too-soon-for-low-traffic-tags/97581#97581). In particular, close votes do not start expiring until a question has 100 views. This question doesn't have 100 views yet (but undoubtedly will very soon due to the attention brought by this meta question).

The change is listed in the [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) (on 2011-07-06). If you're interested in evolutions to the way Stack Exchange works, you should periodically review this question.

Comment: I was the 100th view