# What to do with questions where the user does not reply back?

Tags: discussion

I have faced many times a situation where someone asks a question and does not provide enough information.

In this case, I tend to write a comment or try to reply in a more general fashion.

In a lot of cases, the user does not get back with more information, and so you reach a point where you have open, unanswered questions.

- Do users not get **email** notifications by default for questions they've asked?

Voting down, flagging, proposing to close the question does not always get the question to be set to On Hold or Closed, etc...

The end result is an unending list of unanswered questions.

What does the community think about it?
Is there not the possibility to auto-close a question in such cases? something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Vote to close as this question lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem.
2. Downvote the question.

That's the only two things you can do now, since you already left a comment asking for more information and never heard back.

[image]

---

> Do users not get email notifications by default for questions they've
>   asked?

I think they do by default. However, it's very easy to uncheck the box in your preferences, so you don't receive them. And even if they do receive emails, it doesn't mean they will come back and edit the post.

> Is there not the possibility to auto-close a question in such cases? something else?

Yes, posts can be auto-deleted. See this for how it works
https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/244519

Answer (score 3):

I guess the root cause for these questions remaining open is the huge CV review queue.

A lot of other questions in the queue with different close reasons share the same fate, votes expire and they remain open. Therefore I don't think we should handle these questions any differently. Instead the focus should be on fixing the queue problem.

Comment: Oh, so votes for closing questions can expire? How does one then re-instate a vote? by having another user cast a vote to close?

Comment: @IdanAdar Yes, see [Why do close votes expire?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120896/why-do-close-votes-expire), after your vote expires you cannot vote again.

Comment: That's a problem. Ok...

Comment: @IdanAdar I see you haven't used the [CV review queue](http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats) yet (at least not according to your profile), perhaps you're not yet aware that there are currently over 120,000 questions in that queue, which means the question you voted to close can easily go unnoticed.