# Do close votes on old questions really ever age away?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

So now and then I stumble upon an older question which is essentially a duplicate of a yet older and/or more popular/canonical question. Today's example is [What's the difference between RequestDispatcher.forward() and HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220241/whats-the-difference-between-requestdispatcher-forward-and-httpservletrespons) which is the *n*th duplicate of [RequestDispatcher.forward() vs HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047122/requestdispatcher-forward-vs-httpservletresponse-sendredirect).

However, I can't vote for close because of a close vote I've already cast five years ago.

> You voted to close this question Aug 28 '11 at 13:26

Based on those related meta questions [Why do old expired close votes prevent me from ever voting to close again?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236706/why-do-old-expired-close-votes-prevent-me-from-ever-voting-to-close-again) and [How do close votes age away?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136989/how-do-close-votes-age-away) they should have aged away long ago.

This is not the first time I'm seeing this. It seems that aging of close votes doesn't work very well for "very old" questions. At least, I don't remember seeing above message on a question posted after about 2012.

Comment: In 2012 (the year you mention), SE started leaving a special mark on aged close votes. Any close vote with this special mark can be recast. Your close vote was cast back in 2011, from before they started leaving this mark.

Comment: *Finally*, the question has been marked as a duplicate, after seven years.

Comment: @Sonic: it's not 2023 yet.

Comment: I was referring to the question you linked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Until March 2015](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250223/age-close-votes-after-14-days-regardless-of-views-allowing-recasting), aged away or expired close vote only meant it didn't affect the question status anymore, not that it can be re-cast.

Only when the above feature request has been completed, users could re-cast the expired votes:

> **Allow re-casting votes that've aged away after 14 days**. That is, 14 days (use the same site-configurable value used in #1 here) after your vote has aged away, you're free to cast the same vote again.

So most likely votes expired before the change were unaffected, and still can't be re-cast.

Comment: Ohh, makes sense. I indeed misinterpreted "aged away" as "re-castable".

Comment: Actually, votes cast as early as 2012, when SE began tracking the status of aged close votes, can be recast. This vote was cast in 2011, from before SE started leaving a special mark on aged close votes. See my proposed target for more info.