# Why can't I recast aged close votes and flags that were cast a long time before the change allowing recasting?

Tags: support, flags, vote-to-close, aged-away

In March 2015, [a change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250223/age-close-votes-after-14-days-regardless-of-views-allowing-recasting) was made to the close voting system, to allow users to recast close votes and close flags 14 days after they age away.

However, according to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281141/do-close-votes-on-old-questions-really-ever-age-away), apparently votes that were cast before the change was made cannot be recast. The user in question was trying to recast a vote in 2016, but was prevented because they cast a now-aged vote back in 2011.

Why is this the case? Is this intentional, or is it a bug?

Comment: Why can't I VTC a post [I once voted to close in August 2020?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122976/anyone-with-a-visited-4444-days-4444-consecutive-in-their-profile#comment1225871_122976)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Your vote didn't age away, it successfully closed the post, then it was reopened. You can't recast such close votes; this is intentional to prevent close-warring.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I didn't see or remember seeing the question ever being closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We didn't store a reason for this originally: *all* aged close votes were just marked deleted, regardless of whether they caused the question to be closed or not. (It wasn't possible to retract close votes at the time.)

Eventually - early 2012, or possibly 2013 with some vote statuses backfilled, I forget - we started tracking this. And votes that were marked as "aged away" internally were eligible to be re-cast after that functionality was added in 2015.

Comment: Why can't I recast flags that I cast back in 2014 and were marked "aged away" at the same time of the change?

Comment: I have no idea, since you didn't link to that question.

Comment: Never mind, it looks like I was making a mistake when testing. I just tested again and it seems to work now. As I didn't have an account prior to 2012, I don't know if old flags cast prior to the change and dismissed as aged away in 2015 can be recast.

Comment: If (hypothetically) I encounter a question that I voted to close back before aged close votes were being tracked, and I still believe it should be closed, what should I do? Should I flag for moderator attention? Is this an acceptable use of a sock puppet to cast a recommend closure flag? After all, in spirit, I should be able to recast the vote and have it reviewed for closure again; the only hurdle is purely technical.

Comment: It is not an acceptable use of a sockpuppet, @Sonic. Also, the chances of you finding such a question are not high. Raising the matter on meta is always an option.