# The case of eternal close votes

Tags: bug, vote-to-close

According to [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250453/163653) from 2015, changes were made so that all close votes age away after 14 days, and your ability to cast a close vote on a question you already voted to close resets 14 days after your previous vote ages away. In practice, this means you should be cast a new close vote on a given question every 28 days. And this is my experience, and I think it works well.

Except when it isn't and it doesn't. Here is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7507887/681865) I voted to close in 2011:

[image]

The close vote aged away, but my ability to vote again to close it has never been restored. As a result, there is an 8 year old, completely unanswerable question which I can't do anything about.

Is this really by design? If not, is there an easy fix? The changes to the close voting requirements on Stack Overflow has given new hope to those of us that lurk on minor and not busy tags that we might actually be able to get questions closed, but this is another unexpected roadblock I just tripped over....

Comment: It will roomba in 2 days now ...

Comment: @GhostCat Downvotes are anonymous but I suspect they have been cast on that question to push it into the path of the Roomba.

Comment: @GhostCatsaysReinstateMonica notice the post score requirements  in [roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) ... or use the [forecaster](https://stackapps.com/questions/7239/roomba-forecaster-when-will-the-question-be-roombaed-if-it-wont-why)

Comment: @rene Thanks. Probably some sort of hangover ... I didn't notice the downvotes on the question, I *thought* it was at 0 votes when I clicked it.

Comment: @rene: Thanks for that. The thing is there are more than one question like this. It seems that every circa 2011 question which I close voted and which wasn't closed at the time has the same issue. Also just realized I posted this on the network meta and not the [SO] meta....

Comment: @talonmies yeah, based on your observation it looks like close votes casted before 2015 didn't get expired. I wonder how much there are in this state but that needs a CM/dev to figure out.

Comment: Are you quite sure you didn't *retract* your close vote those years ago? AFAIK, retracted votes mean you can never vote again

Comment: I *never* retract close votes (and you couldn't retract votes in 2011 anyway)

Comment: The answer to Alex's proposed target is correct: prior to 2012, the status of aged close votes wasn't tracked, so votes that were cast prior to them being tracked cannot be recast. The proper procedure is to [raise the matter on the per-site meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313654/why-cant-i-recast-aged-close-votes-and-flags-that-were-cast-a-long-time-before#comment1027722_313657).