# Why is 'viewed x times' shown? What are the advantages of the view count?

Tags: discussion, views

This is a general question. I wonder what advantages there are when showing the number of views for each question.

I would be glad if you convince me that it makes sense!

Maybe there is a study somewhere? I could not find it...

Comment: Well, what does it tell you if your question stays at 30 views?

Comment: I'd like to see a list of all possible advantages, and even disadvantages. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you could tell us what you think doesn't make sense about displaying the view count?

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Might it be difficult to answer this question? Maybe the information about views is not necessary, and I'd like to be convinced that it makes sense to asker and answerer. This is a total basic question, and I could not find arguments, neither pro nor versus.

Comment: There's no need for it to make sense to either Echt; maybe it only makes sense to casual viewers who want to know how popular the question is and therefore whether it's likely trustworthy. That's my point, you can have a list of 100 reasons that don't mean much on their own quite easily. That doesn't explain anything though, which is why I asked _why_ you think it doesn't make sense. If you can't work this out then how do you expect people to be able to convince you?

Comment: Its rise (or lack thereof) is a reasonable indicator for how active your question still is. Lots of views/activity but no answers could tell you something. As could no answers and no more views either.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards View count is about popularity, good. I never looked to the view count in terms of trustworthiness, but on votes for the answer (many votes, trustworthy answer). / The only advantage I personally see is that the asker can hope that his question will be answered soon. Increasing views could mean higher chance that the question gets answered. Could.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I would be glad if you convince me that it makes sense!

My apologies in advance, I'll not try to convince you that it makes sense or not. However, I'll share my views on the view count.

**Utility of View Count:**

**View count** is an indication of **popularity**, how popular a question has been since it was asked. Popularity is not equivalent to usefulness of the question. At Stack Exchange, usefulness is measured by the score (upvotes - downvotes).

For example, [Create a sample login page using servlet and JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981191/create-a-sample-login-page-using-servlet-and-jsp) has a view count of 50,000 but a score of 0. For me that is quite an interesting fact. Definitely Stack Exchange users didn't find this question to be useful so they didn't upvote it. However, many users did view it maybe they stumbled upon it from other search engines.

You may find other such questions from [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=161&tab=votes&q=views%3a40000%20closed%3a0).

**What could low view-count mean?**

If a question is low on view count then it could mean that the post title was not interesting/catchy enough to capture the attention of users. If could also mean that maybe a particular technical area is a low-traffic area. Maybe external search engines ranked it low based on the questions content (so external traffic is not coming to that questions).

**View count used for site moderation:**

[Closed question functionality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question) uses view count as a factor too. [Close votes expire after 4 days have passed since the last close vote and the question has more than **100 views**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97581/166025).

Comment: By giving the search link you actually showed that the view count can be used to find popular questions. You gave +1 pro argument in terms of features. Thanks.

Comment: +1 Questions with high view count but lowly scored answers could well be crying out for a decent canonical answer to be added. Shame there doesn't seem to be a straight forward way of finding these using the search.

Comment: @MartinSmith Good one! :)

Comment: Now, personally, I see the view count as an "attention indicator". In my forums, if a new questions hits 1000 views within one hour I vote it up.